# Acrobat: Font changes on paste

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Using Acrobat Pro CS2, I observe strange behavior to text when pasting a certain diagram exported from Excel as PDF into the current document. This issue concerns the text already in the document, not the text in the diagram itself.
The edges around the text lose their "smoothness", thus aliasing is stronger and the text looks noticeably bolder.

The texts parameters do not change, however. They remain the same typeface, size, etc.

What I tried:

- Copying the text from Document A to the one containing the diagram
- Copying the diagram into Document A
- Importing the diagram into Illustrator and exported as AI, PDF and ESP upfront, before copying into Document A

I of course could export the diagram to a raster format, but really want to avoid this so the diagrams labeling remains in tact (not rasterized). Oh and color space for all documents is CMYK, for what it's worth.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: What is the current document you are trying to put the diagram in? Another PDF?

Comment: Yes, it is another PDF

Comment: I can't see why you get this issue even when exporting from Illustrator! Is it possible the issue comes from your Acrobat Preferences... for example, the "smooth line art" "enhance thin line" in page display in the preferences of Acrobat are not checked?

Answer (score 1):

If the original PDF has the resolution you need, I suggest using the Acrobat *Insert Page* function which will merge the 2 PDF files without the need for copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that simple. DocumentA contains the title for the diagram, DocumentB the diagram itself. I need both on the same page, title and diagram.

Comment: I think what is happening is that the diagram gets rasterized in some way upon export from Excel. What is the original format of Document A? You might have better results keeping everything the Microsoft family - can you merge the 2 pieces in Word, for example?

Comment: Sadly no. I really appreciate the effort for finding another sollution, but there is no way around Acrobat. I will now rasterize the diags, which is rather suboptimal but the only sollution right now, given the timeframe. Regardless, thanks for trying to help out.